# HJM Model proofs

Tags: reference-request, proof, heath-jarrow-morton

I am looking for a source that possibly has the proofs for the material in the first paper on the HJM model Heath, David, et al. “Bond Pricing and the Term Structure of Interest Rates: A New Methodology for Contingent Claims Valuation.” Econometrica, vol. 60, no. 1, 1992, pp. 77–105. JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/2951677.(https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2951677.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Ad6600db7b198f67b597605b247af4c8f). The authors skip some of the proofs. I have found some books that covers some of the proofs but its done only for specific cases and is not as general as this paper. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to be more specific, for example, the proof for which part is missing etc. People can not write an essay here to rephrase the whole paper.

Comment: @Gordon I understand that. This is a reference request. If no such book or source exists with all the proofs I will post a new question requesting proofs for a particular problem. Thank you.

Comment: You may have a look of [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Martingale-Financial-Modelling-Stochastic-Probability/dp/3540209662).

Comment: @Gordon. I have and it is a good source. However, it assumes that the volatility term $\sigma$ is bounded for simplicity. In the paper this is not assumed which makes proving certain things more complicated. (Ex: when proving the discounted bond price is a martingale)